# Question mark converted to %3F in URI

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to get information from an API. When I write the link it doesn't detect the character "?" and it substitutes this char for "%3F" so I can't access to the API.

```dart
final String _charactersUrl = '/api/character/?page=2';
```

I get status code 500 from the API:

```
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/%3Fpage=3
```

The class that gets information from the API

```dart
class Api {

  final String _baseUrl = 'rickandmortyapi.com';
  final String _charactersUrl = '/api/character/?page=2';
  final String _charactersJsonKey = 'results';

  final HttpClient _httpClient = HttpClient();

  Future<List<Character>> getCharacters() async {
    final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, _charactersUrl);
    final response = await _getJson(uri);

    if (response == null || response[_charactersJsonKey] == null) {
      print('Api.getCharacters(): Error while retrieving characters');
      return null;
    }

    return _convert(response[_charactersJsonKey]);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _getJson(Uri uri) async {
    try {
      final request = await _httpClient.getUrl(uri);
      final response = await request.close();

      if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.OK) {
        print('Api._getJson($uri) status code is ${response.statusCode}');
        return null;
      }

      final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      return json.decode(responseBody);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Api._getJson($uri) exception thrown: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  List<Character> _convert(List charactersJson) {
    List<Character> characters = <Character>[];

    charactersJson.forEach((character) {
      characters.add(Character.fromJson(character));
    });

    return characters;
  }
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to show us how you are trying to access the API, i.e. paste the code (do not use screenshots).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Uri` class expects you to use the [`Uri.https` constructor](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.https.html) differently.

The third positional parameter is `queryParameters`, which you should use instead of passing your query parameters to the `unencodedPath`:

```dart
final String _baseUrl = 'rickandmortyapi.com';
final String _charactersPath = '/api/character/';
final Map<String, String> _queryParameters = <String, String>{
  'page': '2',
};

Future<List<Character>> getCharacters() async {
    final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, _charactersPath, _queryParameters);
    ...
```